# Understanding name on German headstone

Tags: palaeography, german-language, grave-marker, nebraska

I can use an online translator to understand the first half: Bertha M, wife of John Shrader, died May 17, 1885. Age 34 years, 6 months, 28 days. This matches my other records for this person, maiden name Beckhardt.

I am having trouble with the bottom part. I am guessing that the bottom part refers to a baby, who died at 4 days. The mother, Bertha, died 3 days later.

There are a few words that I can't read well enough to enter into an online translator, but a German speaker might have better luck. Can someone confirm my interpretation?

[image]

https://www.findagrave.com/memorial/55192909/bertha-m-shrader

Sorry for the poor picture, not mine. Permission given to re-post image by creator.

Comment: A tragic story -- she died a week after giving birth, three days after her child had died. We underestimate how blessed the time and places we live in are.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's what I was able to read so far (original, and translation):

Bertha M.

Frau von
John Shrader
Gest.
Mai 17, 1885
im Alter von
34 Jahr 6 Mon.
und 28 Tage

Im ...
... geliebt

Amale

Tochter von ...
... M. Shrader
Gest.
Mai 14, 1885
Im Alter von 4 Tagen

---

Bertha M.

Wife of
John Shrader
died
May 17, 1885
aged 34 years, 6 months, 28 days

...

Amale

Daughter of J. ahd B. M. Shrader
died
May 14, 1885
aged 4 days

---

As far as I can tell, your interpretation is right: a daughter named "Amale" (which is not a common German name, maybe it's a misspelling of "Amalie", or maybe not) died a few days before her mother.

I'm having difficulties reading the part between the two blocks associated with the persons, which is probably some saying/poem/bible quotation.

Comment: I think that's a 34, not an 84. Makes more sense to be 34 is she had just had a baby!

Comment: "J. u. B. M. Shrader" is probably short for "J. und B. M. Shrader," i.e. "J. and B. M. Shrader," short for "John and Bertha M. Shrader."

Comment: I have never seen ages on tombstones given with this precision - is that typical for that region?

Comment: @Stefan - listing the age to the day is common in *death certificates* from the 1800s and early 1900s. It is not on any of the other Shrader headstones from that region/era that I know of. The age is only listed this way on one other headstone in my family tree, a Dutch ancestor buried in Massachusetts, late 1700s.

Comment: shoover, thanks for the hint. Yes, that's definitely a 34 (I shouldn't have transcribed this late at night...).

Comment: What I think is interesting is that the German appears to be good, but non-native speaker level to me, but I don't know who phrased the inscription. So it might be a dialect speaker, or the text was done in German out of tradition (the Shrader hints at German ancestry).

Comment: @jadepx - FYI, husband John was born in Mecklenburg, immigrated to Nebraska, USA as a young adult, age 45 at time of wife's death.

Comment: @Mattman944 Ah, interesting: The name of the husband was John. That fits the "J.u." -- "John und" under "AMALE". Interesting also that the husband and father is not more prominent; maybe Bertha's family paid for the tombstone. A touching story. Btw, I was able to decipher the inscription, see my answer below.

Answer (score 5):

After guessing a few words of the — is *proverb* the right word for it? — I was able to find it via google on two other entries in findagrave.com, [this one](https://www.findagrave.com/memorial/12299005/frederich-wilhelm-ramsel) and [this one](https://www.findagrave.com/memorial/38828843/johanna-christina_caroline-bergmann).

The complete inscription is very close to

```
     BERTHA M.                            Bertha M.
     Frau von                             Wife of 
   JOHN SHRADER                           John Shrader
       GEST.                              died
    Mai 17, 1885                          May 17, 1885
    im Alter von                          at the age of 
   34 Jahr 6 Mon.                         34 years, 6 months
    und 28 Tage                           and 26 days
 -----------------                        
Im Lande, wo's [or im's?] kein Schei-     In the land, where there is no par-
                  den gibt                                         ting
vereint Gott, die sich hier               God unites those who were in love here
                    geliebt               
                                          
        AMALE                             Amale
    Tochter von J.u.                      daughter od J. a[nd]
     B.M. SHRADER                         B.M. Shrader
        GEST.                             died
     Mai 14, 1885                         May 14, 1885
     im Alter von                         at the age of
         4 Tage.                          4 days.
      -----------
```

The inscription is very fitting the death of a mother and her child.

A few things caught my attention:

- In Germany, the name would typically be spelled S**c**hrader, not Shrader; the variant shown in the inscription seems to match the English spelling. A quick google search [seems to confirm](https://de.namespedia.com/details/Shrader) that the surname spelled this way is chiefly American.
- The dates are given in American notation. In German one would write the day before the month, like [here](https://www.hna.de/bilder/2014/11/12/4442877/2102441152-b6ff3154-cfcd-4a56-9971-835130f016bc-aab.jpg).
- The grammar is a little off: It should be "im Alter von 34 Jahre**n** ... und 28 Tage**n**", likewise with the baby's age.

This fits with the information on the linked website that the grave is in Otoe, Nebraska. According to the [wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Otoe,_Nebraska) the town, founded in 1880, was originally named *Berlin*. "Many of the early inhabitants were German Lutherans". This also fits with the surname *Schrader* which is most frequent in the Lutheran northern parts of Germany.
Bertha and her child died shortly after the town was founded; some people were speaking German there, with an English influence.

Comment: Thanks for the valuable details, especially for the history of the place. This gives interesting context around this family, I think.

Comment: Family name was Schroeder in Germany, I haven't found John's birth record, but I found his sisters. https://genealogy.stackexchange.com/questions/18274/multiple-german-given-names

Comment: Mattman944, I might have found a candidate for John's baptism in May 1840 in Blankenhagen in Archion's collection (German churchbooks, paywall, in case you are not aware of this resource). Is there a way to pass you that information without misusing the comments here? (maybe in another question?)

Comment: @jadepx - excellent, I will ask another question explaining my real goals.