# German Ancestor - Schroeder (Shrader) Connecting Families

Tags: germany, baptism-records

I inherited the German records of my family tree from a distant relative 20 years ago (no sources, just a descendant list). It has special meaning to me because it got me started in Genealogy. Unfortunately, I have found many errors. Below is the present state with many errors corrected and some new information.

My biggest issue right now is inconsistencies in mother Sophia's maiden name: Handen/Harra/Harrar. Below are two examples, but there are many others. I believe that all the Shrader's in my descendant list below are from the same family, but I am not certain.

I found two of the sisters births in German records (mother's maiden name Handen), but I can't find any of the brothers. [Multiple German Given Names](https://genealogy.stackexchange.com/questions/18274/multiple-german-given-names)

Other Shrader family trees on Ancestry.com almost always list the mother's maiden name as Harra. They often omit the sister that is my ancestor, probably because she settled in a different state.

Can someone help me be more certain that this is all the same family? A birth record of one of the brothers with matching parents names would be good evidence.

A bonus would be birth records of the parents, but maybe that should be another question.

Edit: I updated the parents information based on new information. Mother Sophie may have immigrated after her husband died.

[image]
[image]

(third marriage for Fred, first marriage doesn't list mother's name)

[image]

Comment: I'll try my luck in Archion (not sure of how much of the actual pages I can put here, but transcripts will be possible in any case). I can already tell that the maiden name is very probably "Harder" (this is pretty consistent in the records so far).

Comment: When did your GGGparents immigrate? Did you have any children before that? This could help narrowing down the date of marriage.

Comment: @jadepx - Mary Shrader's first child born Aug 1860. I found a "D Reimers" who immigrated from port of Hamburg in 1857 (age 24, which would be correct), no way to know if this is the right person. I have never found them in the 1900 USA census, this would give approx immigration year.

Comment: @jadepx - I finally found Dietrich and Mary Raimer in the 1900 census. Last name transcription was corrupted so badly the search engine couldn't find them. Immigrated 1857, married 43 years in 1900. So, married right about the time they immigrated.

Comment: So far I found baptism records for all kids EXCEPT Fred. Will prepare those into an answer later, then will look after other events (marriages, deaths) in Germany.

Comment: With regard to Mary Shrader and Dietrich Reimer, I found this 1857 marriage in Cuyahoga, OH in FamilySearch: https://www.familysearch.org/ark:/61903/1:1:XDF5-2WB. Could this be the couple in question?

Comment: @jadepx - Yes, that is probably Mary and Dietrich's marriage. Raimer/Reimer is an uncommon name in Ohio. I had assumed that they were married in Germany, single women normally didn't travel alone back then unless they were joining other family members. Her siblings were far away in Nebraska.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have found several of the children in Archion's collection (all records from "Norddeutschland: Landeskirchliches Archiv der Evang.-Luth. Kirche > Kirchenkreis Mecklenburg"). Below are the most relevant excerpts from the records, and their transcripts. As a general note, the spelling of the surname is hard to tell, as "o" and "a" appear very similar in this script. Lines/dashes in table seem to indicate repetition of the information above (I found this used extensively in confirmation records in this community).

There are some phrases, in particular with the godparents that I find hard to decipher, so any suggestions are appreciated.

It appears that the family moves from Blankenhagen to Völkshagen at some point, as indicated by the churchbooks. Both places are very close to each other, in a region east of Rostock.

[image: Baptism record Maria Sophia Dorothea Schröder]
Blankenhagen: Blankenhagen Taufen, Trauungen, Bestattungen 1787-1836, p28

```
Born Sep 26, 1831
Bapt. Sep 26, 1831

Father: Büdner [a special form of crofter specific to Mecklenburg] Johann Christian Heinrich Schroeder/Schraeder
Mother: Sophia Dorothea née Harder
Child: Maria Sophia Dorothea

Godparents:
1. Jgfr. [maid] Sophia Dorothea Harder, in Kösterbek
2. -- Maria Röpke --
3. Maria Dorothea B... g. [born] Ehlert, Blankenhag
```

[image: Baptism record Sophia Maria Elisabeth Schröder]
Blankenhagen: Blankenhagen Taufen, Trauungen, Bestattungen 1787-1836, p28

```
Born Apr 5, 1833
Bapt. Apr 7, 1833

Father: Büdner Johann Christian Schroeder
Mother: Sophia Dorothea née Harder
Child: Sophia Maria Elisabeth

Godparents:
1. Sophia Reimer née Schroeder
2. Maria Anna Jenß Nebenfrau[?], Handels Jäger h ... [this line does not make sense to me yet]
3. Elisabeth Maria Martini née Rath, Volkshagen
```

[image: Baptism record Dorothea Christina Elise Schröder]
Blankenhagen: Völkshagen Taufen, Trauungen, Bestattungen 1787-1836, p20

```
Born Sep 1, 1836
Bapt. Sep 4, 1836

Father: Einl. [prob. Einlieger, maybe "lodger"] Johann Heinrich Christian Schröder
Mother: Sophia Dorothea née Harder
Child: Dorothea Christine Elise

Godparents:
1. Sophia Dorothea Witt née Schumann, Völkshag
2. Distmädch? [guess] Christina Schumann --
3. G...? Elisabeth Schoening, Blankenhag
```

[image: Baptism record Johann Carl Heinrich Schröder]
Blankenhagen: Taufen 1837-1894 p16

```
Born May 6, 1840
Bapt. May 10, 1840

Father: Einl. Johann Heinrich Christian Schröder, Völkshagen
Mother: Sophia Dorothea née Harder
Child: Johann Carl Heinrich

Godparents:
1. ...? Heinrich Harder, Kösterbek
2. ...? Carl Schröder, Hamburg
3. Einl. Johann Dunge, Völkshagen
```

[image: Baptism record Johann Joachim Friederich Schröder]
Blankenhagen: Taufen 1837-1894 p29

```
Born Sep 24, 1843
Bapt. Oct 1, 1843

Father: Einl. Christian Johann Schröder, Völkshagen
Mother: Sophia Dorothea née Harder
Child: Johann Joachim Friederich

Godparents:
1. ...? Johann Kellermann, Völkshagen
2. Bdr. [prob. "Büdner"] Friederich Martienß, --
3. K...? Joachim Harder, Kösterbek
```

I could find neither the baptism record for Henry Schröder in 1852, nor confirmation records for the above children (which would have taken place in the 1840s). Looking around marriage and burial records, I did not encounter the names Schröder and Harder frequently. From these hints, I would guess two things:

1. The family isn't originally from the area (the Harder godparents for example seem to reside in Kösterbek, which is close to Roggentin, also near Rostock).
2. The family resides in a different place from the 1840s.

Comment: Awesome. You deserve to be in the hall of fame for this answer. I will write another question for the parents.

Comment: FYI: I now have DNA match evidence that children born in 1831, 1833, 1843 are from the same parents.