# Finding Shrader birth records

Tags: germany, birth-records, german-language

*jadepx* did an awesome job confirming that all my Shraders are from the same family. [German Ancestor - Schroeder (Shrader) Connecting Families](https://genealogy.stackexchange.com/questions/18280/german-ancestor-schroeder-shrader-connecting-families/18291#18291)

Can someone help find the birth records of the parents?

Johann Christian Heinrich (Christ) Schröeder
b. 20 Feb 1795?, Zarnekow?, Mecklenburg, Germany
d. Bef 1870, prob Germany

Sophia Dorethea (Sophie) Harder
b. 15 Oct 1808, Mecklenburg?, Germany
d. 17 Jun 1873, Nebraska
m. prob Germany

Several people have trees on Ancestry.com that include this Shrader family (with no sources). Most of them omit the daughter that is my ancestor.

I found a entry in an 1819 German census that might be Christ. I can find no records of him ever living in the USA. Several Ancestry.com trees list him dying in Illinois, USA in 1869 (no sources given). But other information indicates that most of the family was living in Nebraska at the time.

I found a grave in Nebraska that is probably Sophie. Christ is not listed in the same cemetery. Sophie was living with one of the children in 1870 (census). Christ is not listed in this census, I assume that he died before then (divorces were rare then). The birth year is hard to read, I think it is 1808, other people have interpreted it as 1805.

[image]

[image]

[image]

https://www.findagrave.com/memorial/55198866/sophie-schrader

This may be Sophie living in Doberan in 1819 census.

[image]

Found this passenger list. Some names and ages are slightly different, but overall it is a good match. Next person listed is Paap, could be the person who married Dora. If this is true, then the census I found for Christ Shrader is wrong. Christ would be born about 1805 according to this passenger list.

I reviewed the USA census records for Henry, birth of 1852 may be wrong, it is probably a year or two earlier.

Maybe someone recognizes the city name.

[image]

Comment: Not sure about the place of birth/residence in the passenger list yet. My best guess right now is something like "Mück hagen", which does not make much sense. There are places with "Müritz" in it to the north. Maybe someone else can make more sense of this.

Comment: Someone on the Ancestry.com forum thinks it is Mönkhagen also spelled Mönchhagen. Based on clues in the birth records, they think that the Harder family is from Koesterbeck.

Comment: Mönchhagen is, at least today, in the same parish as Blankenhagen, I will try to look that up.

Comment: Update: Mönchhagen seems to have been in the parish of Rövershagen at that time (which is not online at Archion yet), as the records in Bentwisch (the other candidate) do not mention that place.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While not exactly the birth records, I found their marriage record based on the improved parish information.

This excerpt is from Archion's collection, "Norddeutschland: Landeskirchliches Archiv der Evang.-Luth. Kirche > Kirchenkreis Mecklenburg", Kessin, Trauungen 1731-1841.

Head of church book page (mind that the year changes between the two snippets)
[image: Header of record page]

```
Tag                                     Day
der Copulation | der Proklamation       of marriage | of proclamation

Name                                    Name
des Bräutigams                          of groom
der Braut                               of bride
des Vaters des Bräutigams               of groom's father
des Vaters der Braut                    of bride's father

Voriger Ehestand                        Previous marriage

Pastor copulans                         Priest who married the couple
```

The relevant entry from 1830:
[image: Record entry]

```
Septbr 24.

D:
13
14
15

Christian Johann Heinrich **Schroeder**
Büdner [crofter] im Blankenhäger Bauern... [not clear to me, maybe some sort of farmer/ownership organization]

Sophia Harder in Koesterbeck

Heinrich Schroeder
Weber zu Beselin [part of Kessin]

Jacob Harder
Hauswirt [I think] zu Koesterbeck

Ber... ledige Personen
```

Answer (score 2):

Found them in the nearby parish of Kessin. The passenger list age is wrong. Listed age is 57, he was really 66. The census I listed is a different Christ Schroder.

The month and the year are wrong on the grave. In my tree, I have seen a year be off by one, or the wrong day, but this is the first time that I have seen the month wrong.

[image]

Comment: Great work! With the updated parish information, I found the marriage, too.